# Como puedo cargar el script de conekta antes de que se cree mi componente de vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, asincronismo

Tengo un componente que muestra la opción de pago con tarjeta.

Estoy intentando cargar el script de conekta solo cuando es necesario. Cuando se renderiza el componente que ocupa el script de conecta en el hook **created** cargo el script.

```
created() {
    if (document.getElementById("conekta")) return; // was already loaded
    var scriptTag = document.createElement("script");
    scriptTag.src = "https://cdn.conekta.io/js/latest/conekta.js";
    scriptTag.id = "conekta";
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(scriptTag);
},
```

Lo que no me gusta de esto es que me generar errores referentes que a que no existe el objeto **Conekta**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pensé en descargar el cdn y cargarlo como un archivo statico utilizando las funciones como **require** o **import** pero esto me causaria problemas si conekta actualiza su script del cdn.

también intente escuchar el evento ready o load del script pero tampoco funciona

```
function loadScript() {
  if (document.getElementById("conekta")) return; // was already loaded
  var scriptTag = document.createElement("script");
  scriptTag.src = "https://cdn.conekta.io/js/latest/conekta.js";
  scriptTag.id = "conekta";
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(scriptTag);

  document.getElementById("conekta").addEventListener("load", function(){
  
     component = { my component };
  });
 
  export default component;
}
loadScript();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te comparto un ejemplo que hice para cargar Conekta en un componente Vue.

```javascript
<template>
  <div id="app" v-show="isLoaded">Conekta cargado</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  data: function () {
    return { isLoaded: false };
  },
  methods: {
    loadConekta: function () {
      const script = document.createElement("script");
      script.src = "https://cdn.conekta.io/js/latest/conekta.js";
      script.id = "conekta-script";

      const self = this;
      script.onload = function () {
        if (!window.Conekta) return void console.error("Conekta is not set");
        self.isLoaded = true;
      };

      script.async = true;
      document.body.appendChild(script);
    },
  },
  created() {
    if (!this.isLoaded)
       this.loadConekta();
  },
  mounted() {
    if (this.isLoaded)
       window.Conekta.setPublicKey("");
  },
};
</script>
```